# How to tell where the given method/property is declared?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Say I have a class (shown as **meta data**) -- code lies in dll:

```
class Foo : IA, IB, IC, ID...
{
   public void Bar(); // implementation
}
```

I would like to know where this `Bar` method was **declared** -- in IA, or IB, or... ... or it is fresh implementation -- without referring to any external sources like MSDN.

Can I do this in Visual Studio? If yes -- how?

*If this was editable file (like my own code) this would be easy -- simply comment out for a while this method and see which interface becomes flagged.*

Comment: You should be able to press F12 while hovering on it

Comment: This can be done using ReSharper for example. Alternatviyl simply right-click the method-->Find All References

Comment: @AlfieGoodacre, thank you, but it goes to definition.

Comment: On a side note, it's possible for all of these interfaces to declare `Bar()`.

Comment: Place your cursor on the code and right click and choose `Go to definition`  else press F12

Comment: @HimBromBeere, thank you for Resharper hint, as for all references it will find the definition I am looking at and all **my** references -- so it goes "outside", while I need it to go "inside".

Comment: @Reddy, see above, it does not move.

Comment: If you need more than "_the definition_" you probably need a disassembler.  Try DotPeek for free from the same folks as Resharper.

Comment: @astrowalker is your Interface code in a `.dll` file?

Comment: @DavidTansey, I need it go from class (which I look at) to interface. Or tell me it is new (from scratch) implementation.

Comment: @Reddy, yes, all I see is meta data of the class.

Comment: @astrowalker then you have to use some tools to decomplie your code like, DotPeek or JustDecompile etc.. But even with this approach the code is not guaranteed to be 100% accurate.

Comment: @Reddy, thank you, in other words with just VS it is impossible. Could you please post your comment as regular answer (I cannot accept comment as solution).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are looking to get the source code of any `.dll` file you cannot do it with Visual Studio, But you can make use of decompiler tools like [JustDecomplie](http://www.telerik.com/products/decompiler.aspx) , [dotPeek](https://www.jetbrains.com/decompiler/) etc

But even with these decompilers it is not guaranteed to get back the source code 100% accurately.

Comment: Thank you very much! One thing that strikes me as odd is Visual Studio is capable of getting meta data from those interfaces as well, I hit "F12" of any of those names, and I can see all declarations, what I miss is "connecting the dots".

Comment: @astrowalker the `.dll` files will have information of the code within along with versions and other stuff.. Hence visual studio will be able to show you the metaData

Answer (score 0):

Remove the word `public` from the method and put, one at a time, `IA.` and all the other interfaces in front of the method name, then try to compile.

```
 void IA.Bar() {
 }
```

Note that more than one interface may have this method so you can try them all, or just paste in one copy of the method for each interface and see which ones work.

(This, by the way, is how you make different implementations for methods with the same name and signature from two different interfaces. I had to do this the other day with an indexer that one interface expected to be read-only and the other read/write. When the object is cast to one of the interfaces it uses the corresponding method.)

Alternately, ReSharper can do this for you. Simply hover over the method name with Resharper on.

Comment: The problem is that as I wrote I see meta data, the code is not mine, it lies in some dll.

Comment: Are you saying it didn't work? What does "I see meta data" mean? Did you try it? When you say "see where the method was declared" did you mean identify which interface it came from, or actually look at the source code--because if you mean the latter, your question is really, really unclear.

Comment: I didn't try it, because I know you cannot edit meta data or compile it. So this advice is irrelevant. Try it if you don't believe me, write any code with for example type `String`, place cursor on `String`, hit "[F12]" you will get meta data of String. As for question "see where the method was declared" did you mean identify which interface it came from" -- this one.

Comment: Oh, I see. I thought this was code in your own project (how on earth can you decompile but not be able to jump to the source of a method?). Can you not copy and paste the source code you're looking at into your own project in a temporary file, and make the modifications there, to see which one it is?

Comment: "how on earth can you decompile but not be able to jump to the source of a method?" I don't understand -- it is exactly behavior you can see, VS just shows the "surface" of given entity. "Can you not copy and paste the source..." In theory yes, but given dependencies it is easier for me to do other tricks, like checking the interfaces manually. I was hoping for something automatic which would eliminate human error (and burden).

Comment: Then my best recommendation is to buy a license for ReSharper, or have your company do it, and you will be in heaven!